# Import .shp into postgre using ogr2ogr

Tags: qgis, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to import a .shp into postgre using ogr2ogr but i'm stuck with an error with the select clause, any ideas?

```
##vsmap_path=vector
##millesime=number 2015

from qgis.core import *
import os


param = {'host':'x.xxx.xx.xx','dbname':'xxxxx' ,'port':'xxxx','user':'xxxxx','password':'xxxxxx'}

ogrPath = "/".join(QgsApplication.prefixPath().split("/")[:-2])+"/bin/"#Definie le chemin de OGR


vsmapLayer=processing.getObject(vsmap_path)#Transforme la couche en objet
vsmapName = vsmapLayer.name()+'_'+str(millesime) #Change le nom de le couche

commande="""ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" -a_srs "EPSG:2154" PG:"host='{host}' dbname='{dbname}' port='{port}' user='{user}' password='{password}'" -lco SCHEMA="0-reseau" -lco OVERWRITE=YES  -lco FID=pkey -sql "SELECT lib_rte FROM {vsmap} WHERE gestionnaire='DIRNO'" '{vsmap_path}' --config OGR_TRUNCATE=YES PG_USE_COPY=YES""".format(vsmap=vsmapName,vsmap_path=vsmap_path,**param)

new_commande = "echo import en cours... & "+ogrPath+commande
os.system(new_commande)
```

Comment: Write first a plain command line ogr2ogr command before adding scripting. How would you write it?